# Does flutter repo have to be cloned in order to setup Flutter

Tags: flutter

After the Flutter 1.0 release, I am following the steps to setup the flutter development environment.

In the steps (as seen in the attached screenshot), it says to update $PATH twice, once with the path to the flutter tool

```
export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin
```

And again with the path to the flutter git directory

```
export PATH=$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin
```

Is it really necessary to update the PATh twice in order to get a flutter environment going or has the documentation for Flutter not been updated after 1.0 GA release of Flutter?

[image: Flutter Docs]

Comment: It's the easiest way, especially if you want to update or switch channel (stable, master, dev ...)

Comment: to be exact flutter repository is the fluttter Sdk

Answer (score 2):

No, you can just download a zip with any version of flutter you want with no gitHub involved. Either way you need to setup your flutter environment variable and link it to the directory to where you have flutter installed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really necessary to update the PATh twice in order to get a
>   flutter environment going or has the documentation for Flutter not
>   been updated after 1.0 GA release of Flutter

The answer is no.

You only have to do it once, the first command is supposed to be executed in the terminal while you're in the directory that contains the flutter folder. However, this will only give you access to the flutter command for the duration of your shell session, that means if you close your terminal window it will not be available anymore.

If you want it to permanently add it to your path then the process is slightly different and it depends on your OS. For Mac which is my case you have to edit the file .bash_profile (Or create it if you haven't already) and add the following line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Projects/flutter/bin
```

I created a Projects folder in my home directory and unzipped flutter there. You should replace "$HOME/Projects" with the absolute path to the flutter folder in your system. If you're in windows there's a GUI to add items to your path.